# How do I get an Atheros AR9285 wireless card working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, atheros

Hi I have a Sony Laptop with Sandy Bridge chipset. I installed the new version of Ubuntu 11.10 because of I read that this release should have support for this chipset. In fact, almost all devices of my laptop are working fine, but the wireless card can not be enable. I found several links to older versions, but I guess all of them were design to work with kernels 2.X.X so I did not tried them. Is there any way to repair this at this time ?

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 90:00:4e:c7:44:15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:d2500000-d250ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 78:84:3c:96:cd:a0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.67 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 memory:d1400000-d143ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
ana@freud:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: just to confirm that this isnt a kernel/block issue - please add to your question the output of `sudo lshw -class network` and also `rfkill list`

Comment: Can anyone help me to format this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks remarkably similar to the linked question below.

In your last trace - acer_wmi wireless kernel module is soft-blocked - this is causing the "DISABLED" message in the first trace.

Try blacklisting the acer_wmi kernel module as per the linked question and accepted answer.

---

Linked Question:

1. [Wubi install cannot see/connect to any wifi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57360/wubi-install-cannot-see-connect-to-any-wifi/57367#57367)

Comment: WoW !!! This works perfect for me. Thanks a lot fossfreedom ! Just one more question. As long as I get updates I need to modify this configuration file again ?

Comment: no - since it is blacklisted you dont need to worry.  However, just occasionally, remove the blacklisting to see if any newer kernels released fixes this bug.